# Cannot connect on MMSql database

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Please help I am getting the following error in my asp application,

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>
> Cannot open database "mydb" requested by the login. The login failed.

I am pretty sure that my user has the rights on the database and that its credentials are right.

I am at a dead end and have no idea what else to try...

Comment: What does "pretty sure" mean?

Comment: "I am pretty sure "... You are definitely wrong.

Comment: Pretty sure means that I copied pastes the connection credentials from files that havent't been edited for years. Whatever changes happened happened in the database server. Instead of being unhelpful why don't try and help?

Comment: @George, you didn't just copy a connection string, you restored a backup of a database to a completely different server. If you're going to attack the help, at least be truthful.

Comment: I didn't restore the backup to a different server. I restored it to the same mssql server. It's a little difficult to do things to wrong servers if you are connected with RDP to the right one.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the default database for the login, or the database explicitly mentioned in the connection string, is offline or no longer exists. Have you checked through another tool (e.g. Management Studio), using another login (e.g. sa or an administrator), that `mydb` is actually online and accessible? Did you check the state of the database using:

```
SELECT state_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'mydb';
```

? Is your database set to Auto-Close? Has this login ever been able to connect to this database? When was the last time?

Lots of things to check.

We know the database is online, next let's make sure the login actually has a user in the database. Does this query return a result?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals AS s
INNER JOIN mydb.sys.database_principals AS d
ON s.sid = d.sid
WHERE s.name = N'your_login_name';
```

Comment: @GeorgeB ok, what about all my other questions?

Comment: It returns 'ONLINE'.
Here is the thing I deleted a domain from my plesk in order to save some space in the server's disk since wasn't being used anymore. 

THe particular domain had another mssql database and the developers for some reason hat the database of the deleted domain connected to the site that has the connection issues. I recreated the domain and the database and restored the db from a .bak file I had (thank God!). After I restored the second database the site couldn't connect to any of the databases.

Comment: What does "deleted domain from my plesk" mean? What is a plesk? How do you delete a domain?

Comment: By plesk I mean Parallels PLesk Panel and I checked the checkbox next to it and hit the delete button.

Comment: Oke, George B some people are trying to help and and they invest time for YOU. So please be so kind to update your question, write down what you have done... those nice people ask lots of questions, so go ahead and answer them.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, ensure that the following conditions are met:

The Windows NT account is mapped to a SQL account.

The User ID in the connection string is valid and is not blank.

Set standard security in SQL Server Enterprise Manager. To implement SQL Server standard security, follow these steps:
From SQL Enterprise Manager, right-click the SQL Server name that appears in the Server Manager window, and then click Properties. (For SQL Server version 6.5 click Configure).
Click Security Options, and then click Standard and Windows. (For SQL Server version 6.5 click Standard).
The Password Synchronization option is turned off for that project if you are running under Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS) 4.0.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/306586